# How to access Dynamic BaseEventData from C# script using EventTrigger, Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onclick, onclicklistener, eventtrigger

I have a code here, where I want to call a function when a pointer click happens.

```
EventTrigger trigger = instance.AddComponent<EventTrigger>();
var pointerClick = new EventTrigger.Entry();
pointerClick.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerClick;
pointerClick.callback.AddListener(delegate { UIController.Click(???); });
trigger.triggers.Add(pointerClick);
```

Now, I want to know if the click was a left or right one.
Code from this thread: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-detect-handle-right-click.355146/

```
public void Click(BaseEventData bed)
{
        PointerEventData ped = (PointerEventData)bed;
        Debug.Log("Button: " + ped.pointerId);

        // pointerId will be -1 for left mouse button, -2 for right
}
```

(Based on the result I have to call other methods - it is just not important here.)

The problem is that I don't know how to give the `BaseEventData` argument input for the function.
I know, in the inspector there is Dynamic BaseEventData but in script?

What to feed as the argument input (`BaseEventData bed` for `Click()`)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare UIController.Click as follows:

```
public void Click( BaseEventData bed )
{
    // ...
}
```

Then: `pointerClick.callback.AddListener( UIController.Click );`

To determine the clicked button, use PointerEventData's **button** property, NOT **pointerId** property:

```
if( ped.button == PointerEventData.InputButton.Left )
{
    // Left clicked
}
```

Comment: In case Click() has other arguments, how to pass them from call place?

Comment: `pointerClick.callback.AddListener( (bed) => UIController.Click( bed, otherArguments ) );`. You can even pass only the clicked button (`bed.button`), not the whole BaseEventData. Note that you can't remove this listener using RemoveListener.